# JS arguments in a function with slice() return undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass two arguments in a function that has String.prototype.slice(), but the console keeps on returning this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined".

Aren't the arguments supposed to be passed?

```js
const testText = '<p style='color: red;'>This is a test</p>'
const testParagraph = document.getElementById('test')

const message = (paragraph, originText) => {
  let i = 0,
    text, isTag
  const speed = 50
  text = originText.slice(0, ++i)
  if (text === originText) return
  paragraph.innerHTML = text
  const char = text.slice(-1)
  if (char === '<') isTag = true
  if (char === '>') isTag = false
  if (isTag) return message()
  setTimeout(message, speed)
}

message(testParagraph, testText)
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please first fix the error you get when you nest the same kind of quotes `const testText = '<p style='color: red;'>This is a test</p>'`

Comment: setTimeout(message, speed) does not pass any text so second time around the parameters are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places where a recursive call of `message` function may happen:

```
if (isTag) return message()
setTimeout(message, speed)
```

In both cases `message` function is called without arguments. Due to this `paragraph` are `originText` parameters are associated with `undefined` value. Then it tries to call `.slice` on `undefined` which raises the error.

You need to pass arguments to a recursive call, since it (like a regular function invocation) creates a new execution context with it's one lexical environment.

```
if (isTag) return message(arg1, arg2)
setTimeout(message.bind(null, arg1, arg2), speed)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm now facing a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error but I'll see what I can do

Comment: You are welcome! "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error usually happens due to reaching the limit of recursion depth. Make sure that you either have a correct exit condition defined within the recursive function or (if you need to run the function constantly) each recursive call is wrapped in `setTimeout` (in this way, next recursive call will happen outside of the current event loop iteration).